# gcc error cannot compile exectables while installing xapian-core

Tags: ruby, gcc, autoconf, xapian

Iam getting the error while installing the gem xapian-core .
It was saying that "configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
 "

Here is the log file generated.

```
    This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by xapian-core configure 1.2.7, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1 --exec-prefix=/home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = ip-10-28-13-19
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 3.0.0-16-virtual
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #29-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 14 15:04:02 UTC 2012

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin
PATH: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin
PATH: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin
PATH: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2767: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2835: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2846: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2896: result: yes
configure:3037: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:3076: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:3089: checking for gawk
configure:3119: result: no
configure:3089: checking for mawk
configure:3105: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:3116: result: mawk
configure:3127: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3149: result: yes
configure:3224: checking how to create a ustar tar archive
configure:3237: tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.25
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
configure:3240: $? = 0
configure:3280: tardir=conftest.dir && eval tar --format=ustar -chf - "$tardir" >conftest.tar
configure:3283: $? = 0
configure:3287: tar -xf - <conftest.tar
configure:3290: $? = 0
configure:3303: result: gnutar
configure:3347: checking build system type
configure:3361: result: i686-pc-linux-gnu
configure:3381: checking host system type
configure:3394: result: i686-pc-linux-gnu
configure:3435: checking how to print strings
configure:3462: result: printf
configure:3495: checking for style of include used by make
configure:3523: result: GNU
configure:3593: checking for gcc
configure:3609: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3620: result: gcc
configure:3849: checking for C compiler version
configure:3858: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3869: $? = 0
configure:3858: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,go --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 
configure:3869: $? = 0
configure:3858: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3869: $? = 4
configure:3858: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3869: $? = 4
configure:3889: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3911: gcc   -R/home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/lib conftest.c  >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized option '-R'
configure:3915: $? = 1
configure:3953: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "xapian-core"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xapian-core"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.2.7"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "xapian-core 1.2.7"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://xapian.org/bugs"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "xapian-core"
| #define VERSION "1.2.7"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3958: error: in `/home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/ext/xapian-core-1.2.7':
configure:3960: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i686-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_BUILD_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_BUILD_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=-R/home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/lib
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=i686-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_prog_tar_ustar=gnutar

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/ext/xapian-core-1.2.7/missing --run aclocal-1.11'
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} /home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/ext/xapian-core-1.2.7/missing --run tar'
AM_CXXFLAGS=''
ANSI_CXXFLAGS=''
AR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/ext/xapian-core-1.2.7/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/ext/xapian-core-1.2.7/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOM4TE=''
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/ext/xapian-core-1.2.7/missing --run automake-1.11'
AWK='mawk'
BUILD_BACKEND_BRASS_FALSE=''
BUILD_BACKEND_BRASS_OR_CHERT_OR_FLINT_FALSE=''
BUILD_BACKEND_BRASS_OR_CHERT_OR_FLINT_TRUE=''
BUILD_BACKEND_BRASS_TRUE=''
BUILD_BACKEND_CHERT_FALSE=''
BUILD_BACKEND_CHERT_TRUE=''
BUILD_BACKEND_FLINT_FALSE=''
BUILD_BACKEND_FLINT_TRUE=''
BUILD_BACKEND_INMEMORY_FALSE=''
BUILD_BACKEND_INMEMORY_TRUE=''
BUILD_BACKEND_REMOTE_FALSE=''
BUILD_BACKEND_REMOTE_TRUE=''
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CC_FOR_BUILD=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
DLLTOOL=''
DOCUMENTATION_RULES_FALSE=''
DOCUMENTATION_RULES_TRUE=''
DOT=''
DOXYGEN=''
DOXYGEN_DOT_PATH=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GREP=''
HELP2MAN=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS='-R/home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/lib'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBRARY_VERSION_INFO='26:1:4'
LIBRARY_VERSION_SUFFIX=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAINTAINER_NO_DOCS_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_NO_DOCS_TRUE=''
MAKEINDEX=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/ext/xapian-core-1.2.7/missing --run makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='xapian-core'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://xapian.org/bugs'
PACKAGE_NAME='xapian-core'
PACKAGE_STRING='xapian-core 1.2.7'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='xapian-core'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.2.7'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERL=''
PNGCRUSH=''
QUIET=''
RANLIB=''
RST2HTML=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SHLIBEXT=''
STLPORT_CXXFLAGS=''
STLPORT_INCLUDE=''
STLPORT_LIBS=''
STRIP=''
USE_WIN32_UUID_API_FALSE=''
USE_WIN32_UUID_API_TRUE=''
USE_ZLIB_VG_FALSE=''
USE_ZLIB_VG_TRUE=''
VALGRIND=''
VERSION='1.2.7'
VPATH_BUILD_FALSE=''
VPATH_BUILD_TRUE=''
XAPIAN_LDFLAGS=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
am__tar='tar --format=ustar -chf - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='tar -xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i686-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i686'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='/home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1'
host='i686-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='i686'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
incdir='${prefix}/include'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1/ext/xapian-core-1.2.7/install-sh'
ldflags=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
link_all_deplibs_CXX=''
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='/bin/mkdir -p'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/home/ubuntu/.bundler/tmp/1841/gems/xapian-core-1.2.7.1'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "xapian-core"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "xapian-core"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.2.7"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "xapian-core 1.2.7"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://xapian.org/bugs"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "xapian-core"
#define VERSION "1.2.7"

configure: exit 77
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 3):

This ticket on github had some helpful links: a patch you can apply and an alternative more-up-to-date version of the xapian-full gem: https://github.com/danmunn/redmine_dmsf/issues/62

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your gcc isn't letting you specify library search paths with `-R`.  If you can find the offending line (looks like it's compiling `conftest.c` in xapian-core's source) and change `-R` to `-Wl,-R`, it may work.

This [thread](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2001-05/msg00086.html) is relevant.

Comment: How can I do that . chamging  -R to -Wl,-R

Comment: You need to see the source tree that your install command unpacks.  That may need some fancy footwork, though.  Frankly, you should go find the package maintainers and open a bug.